# EXT JS - which is better to have navigation between pages? To have different html files or single html file and different views

Tags: extjs

EXT JS - which is better to have navigation between pages? To have different html files or single html file and different views considering the fact that all the files reside on the server.

Basically what i want to know is in sencha touch it makes sense to have single page architecture. But how about ext js ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second question first:

ExtJS is designed for single page application. Go for it, you then don't need to ask yourself the first question.

First question:

In ExtJs, you don't have to think so much in terms of html files, because you generally only have one.
If you really want to have more than one html file, you would probably choose to use the same js file on both and include in the html a kind of a trigger which defines what part of code is executed. But anyway, I would not recommend you to go that way.